# I'm trying to return the AppPool status within a batch script using Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying something like this

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ('
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Invoke-Command -ComputerName <AServerNAme> -ScriptBlock { Get-WebAppPoolState AppPoolName }
 ') do set "value=%%a"
echo What is %value%
```

I want the value to contain stopping, stopped, starting...etc, but all I can get back is null

Thanks In Advance

Comment: If you use `usebackq`, your PowerShell command must be enclosed in `\``, not `'`

Comment: Yes...they're right after the (  and before the other )

Comment: These are `'`, not `\``

Comment: DUH...I put my glasses on and you're right I had ' and not `...corrected them and now I get What is "IsInstance      : True" instead of nothing

Comment: You will probably want the string value property from that object, not the object itself, i.e. `For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "Invoke-Command -ComputerName <AServerNAme> -ScriptBlock {(Get-WebAppPoolState AppPoolName).Value}"') Do Set "value=%%G"`

Comment: Yes, that fixed it...Thanks...I don't know much about powershell other than how to google a question, so what made the difference between what I had and what you suggested?  What 'How to.." book would you recommend for powershell.  Also how do I give you credit for your answer?  Many...MANY...thanks!!

Comment: @SockoJimBob, I have added my comment as an answer for you to credit as requested. Please in future, tag people into your comments, if you are replying directly to them. I only noticed this by luck, when you '@MemberName', that person is notified of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from your incorrect use of the 'USEBACKQuotes' option in your `For` loop, *(because you weren't using them)*, you also need to define your `value` variable using the string value of the object's property, not the object itself.

I would therefore advise that you use something more like this:

```sh
Set "value="
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command
 "Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {(Get-WebAppPoolState AppPoolName).Value}"
 2^>NUL') Do Set "value=%%G"
If Defined value Echo What is %value%
```

You will also note that I have removed the `-ExecutionPolicy` option, because that is usually used for running PowerShell scripts *(`-File`)*, not for commands *(`-Command`)*.

Comment: I'm an old dog learning new tricks...thanks!  When you google for answers and you find something that works, it's great, but why it works it's unknown to me

Comment: @Compo Your first suggestion where you stated I would want the string value works find, but the second one where you are using If DEFINED doesn't work. I also was wondering why use %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  instead of just powershell.exe....Thanks

Comment: I used `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` instead of `powershell.exe` because it is the safest way to ensure that the command used is the one I want, and not some other executable named `powershell.exe`, located in the current directory, or some other location within `%PATH%`. It is always safer to not assume things, by using robust code.